# Can be connect iphone to iphone using BLE?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm quite new to objective-c programming and I have a question about BLE. I need to confirm that I can do iphone-to-iphone BLE: (a) discover; (b) pair; (c) exchange identity data? As far as I know, 2 Idevices want to connect, they need using GameKit Bluetooth, so 2 Idevices can not connect by using BLE,is it right? Please give me any suggestions. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

iOS devices can communicate with each other and other peripherals over BLE using the [Core Bluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html) framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect two device using BLE.

Take a look to the [CoreBluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html) framework's documentation.

And then take a look to the example of apple [BTLE Central Peripheral Transfer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012927) where show how to transfer data from an iOS device in CoreBluetooth Peripheral Mode to another in Central Mode, and the example suggested by @indragie: [BTLE Central Peripheral Transfer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Listings/BTLE_Transfer_BTLECentralViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012927-BTLE_Transfer_BTLECentralViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6)

Also yo can take a look to the project of RedBear: [BLE iOS](https://github.com/RedBearLab/iOS)

In that project there are some examples of how to use.

Like #indragie say, it isn't a very well piece of code but you can take a look.

Comment: RedBearLab's project is a Core Bluetooth wrapper for communicating exclusively with their BLE Shield board for Arduino, so it may not be applicable in the general case. Having used it before, it's not a very well written piece of code so I would recommend against the practices used in it.

Comment: Maybe not very well but simple. He can take a look to the code. But my recommendation is to see the official documentation. +1 to your post. :)

Comment: Agreed, it's fairly easy to get by on just the documentation, but if the OP is looking for an example I would recommend Apple's Core Bluetooth sample code: https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/samplecode/TemperatureSensor/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012194-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Comment: Mmm. I would recommend https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012927, that connect an iOS device in Peripheral mode to an iOS device in Cental Mode.

Comment: You mean I can communicate iphone to iphone use BLE?

Comment: And I have any questions: Iphone can communicate to other iphone and other BLE Device at the same time ?

Comment: Yes to both questions.